# Is the gamble Adam Sandler bet on in a high-end restaurant legal?

Tags: plot-explanation, uncut-gems

In the movie, Uncut Gems, Adam Sandler walks into a restaurant and bets 24G(24,000) dollars with a well dressed guy sitting and eating at a table.

Adam Sandler tells this guy what stats he bets on in an upcoming NBA game and this well dressed guy writes them down on a piece of paper.

Later in the movie, Adam Sandler makes lots of money from betting in a proper Casino, which is legal.

I am wondering if the first bet in a restaurant is legal? Given it looks so un-official and casual.

Comment: Not related to your question: What is “24G dollars”?

Comment: [haven't seen the movie, it's just a question] - Isn't that guy simply a bookie (means: illegal)? As any official office would deliver a proper receipt for the money/bet, not write it on a piece of paper.

Comment: @ToddWilcox, 24,000, I used the exact expression from the movie. Updated my question, thanks

Comment: @OldPadawan, thanks, I thought ~bookie~ meant accoutant. I got it now

Comment: Are sure they didn’t say "24Gs" and not "24G dollars"? A “G” or "grand" is one thousand **dollars**, it is not simply one thousand. There’s no such thing as "24G miles" or "24G cookies". In other words, "24G dollars" means "24,000 dollars dollars". "24Gs" means "24,000 dollars".

Comment: Interesting side note: "bookie" is short for "book maker", which means a person who runs an unlicensed betting system. "Bookkeeper" means accountant.